# Calculating Enthalpy of formation versus Calculating Enthalpy of a reaction not occurring at standard conditions

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, physical-chemistry, chemical-potential, chemical-compounds

My understanding of Hess's law and its use in determining the change of enthalpy of a reaction has been challenged recently.

Up until recently, I thought that the only way to calculate a chemical reaction's change of enthalpy was to use its intermediate chemical reactions and their associated enthalpies (usually provided in a question). So, I would just re-arrange the intermediate reactions so that when combined the compounds and elements would be located on the appropriate side of the yield sign (matching the main reaction). Additionally, I would alter their enthalpies at the same time. Finally, I would add all of the intermediate reaction enthalpies and their sum would be the correct change in enthalpy of the main reaction.

However, I learned that when calculating the change in enthalpy of formation you do not simply add all of the other intermediate reaction's change in enthalpy. Instead, after arranging the other reactions appropriately and altering their mole coefficients and making the same changes to their enthalpies, you are supposed to add the reactants together and the products together and then subtract the reactants from the products. Why? This seems to ignore the fact that energy and enthalpy are state functions. Why must I combine the enthalpies of formation in this particular way if enthalpy is path independent?

I am only studying chemistry at a college level. Though at the college level, I am only studying the basics of chemistry. Please consider this when replying to my question. This community is very smart and seems to be, generally, at a level of understanding far above my own. So, again, please do your best to explain the answer at my level.

Thank you.

Comment: I find this very confusing.  It would be very helpful if you could provide a specific example.

Comment: I realized I posted my question in the wrong forum. But, an example would be Find the change in enthalpy for the following reaction: S + O2(g) --> SO2(g). Then the following two equations are provided: S + 3/2O2 --> SO3 (DeltaH = -395 kJ); 2SO2 _ O2 --> 2SO3 (Delta = -198.2 kJ).  An example of Enthalpy of formation would be: Using a table determine the standard enthalpy of formation of NO2 (4NH3 + 7O2 --> 4NO2 + 6H2O). I would have posted a picture if I was able to.

Comment: So you would use the enthalpies of formation of ammonia and water in conjunction with the heat of this reaction (at standard conditions)?